# How to create a path from coordinates on threejs

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

i have an array of coordinates (from google maps navigation API). i tried to plot coordinates on a sphere and it works.but my goal is to extract the shape of the path(by combining all the coordinates points.please suggest me a solution..thanks advance..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to draw a map on a plane, then try this lib (for me it worked with r81): https://github.com/jdomingu/ThreeGeoJSON

```
drawThreeGeo(json, radius, shape, {options});
```

`shape` can be '*sphere*' or '*plane*'

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted, if it solved your problem, please.

Comment: doesnt explain how to make a path, only how to draw a path on to somethng. how can one make a unique independent 3d path ?

Comment: @bluejayke "_a unique independent 3d path_" explains even less. You could have make a new more detailed question with explanatory picture of desired result.

Comment: "Looks like you want to draw a map on a plane" OP said nothng about map on a plane, OP asked for a *path*, not a map, do you have an " explanatory picture of desired result" in your answer?

Comment: @bluejayke Find the link to a github in my answer, there you'll find a live demo which worth 1000 pics. Are you looking for an answer or just demanding of me something in a question that was asked 4 years ago?

Comment: dont see why the time should mat oyr